# unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body but found: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, retrofit2

Am working with SOAP XML I have validate my xml online it's fine, but when send to server am getting error message "unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body but found: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope", this is the xml am sending

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:pos="http://pos/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <pos:balanceInquiry>
            <iccData></iccData>
            <pinBlock></pinBlock>
            <terminalId></terminalId>
        </pos:balanceInquiry>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have removed values in tags everything remained the same.

```
@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace( prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "pos", reference = "http://pos/")
})

public class XMLRequestEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soapenv:Header", required = false)
    private XMLRequestHeader header;

    public XMLRequestHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(XMLRequestHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

@Root(name = "soapenv:Header", strict = false)
public class XMLRequestHeader {

```
@Element(name = "soapenv:Body", required = false)
private XMLRequestBody body;

public XMLRequestBody getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(XMLRequestBody body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

```
    @Root(name = "soapenv:Body", strict = false)



     public class XMLRequestBody {
    @Element(name = "pos:balanceInquiry",required = false)



private XMLBalanceInquiry xmlBalanceInquiry;



 public XMLBalanceInquiry getXmlBalanceInquiry() {
        return xmlBalanceInquiry;
    }



  public void setXmlBalanceInquiry(XMLBalanceInquiry xmlBalanceInquiry) {

        this.xmlBalanceInquiry = xmlBalanceInquiry;
    }
    }






 @Root(name = "pos:balanceInquiry", strict = false)
public class XMLBalanceInquiry {



@Element(name = "iccData", required = false)
    private String emvData;

    @Element(name = "pinBlock", required = false)
    private String pinBlock;



 @Element(name = "phoneNo", required = false)
    private String phoneNo;

    @Element(name = "terminalId", required = false)
    private String terminalId;



  public String getEmvData() {
        return emvData;
    }



 public void setEmvData(String emvData) {
        this.emvData = emvData;
    }



 public String getPinBlock() {
        return pinBlock;
    }



public void setPinBlock(String pinBlock) {
        this.pinBlock = pinBlock;
    }




  public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }




 public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }



 public String getTerminalId() {
        return terminalId;
    }



   public void setTerminalId(String terminalId) {
        this.terminalId = terminalId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this from a server or from Android?

Comment: @SlobodanAntonijević am getting from server

Comment: Have you confirmed that beyond any doubt you're sending the correct request? If so the problem is on the server's side, not yours.